# How to calculate Expected Value in this Problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

In a parking lot there are $2n$ parking slots, ordered in a line from left to right, with n cars and n trucks parked in uniformly random order. A car is considered to be stuck if:

1. It's not in first or last parking slot.
2. AND, There is a truck on its left and its right.

Computer the probability that any given car is stuck and the expected value.

My try:

For probability:

The probability for first condition is ${(2n-2)}/{2n}$ and The probability for second condition is (1/n)*(1/(n-1)) so we get: ${(2n-2)}/{2n}*(1/n)*(1/(n-1))$.

I'm not sure if this is right at all, and stuck calculating expected value, I know that:

$E(X)=\sum_x x*P_X(x)$

Comment: Not following your calculation of the probability.  Say $n$ is very large.  Then we can ignore the small effect of dependency (and we can ignore the case where the car is at an end).  In that case, the probability that a car is stuck is $\frac 14$.  Whatever formula you get must be close to that for large $n$, but your formula gives $0$ in the limit.

Answer (score 1):

On the calculation of desired probability,

As the given car cannot be in the first or the last parking slot, the probability of that is $\displaystyle \frac{2n-2}{2n} = \frac{n-1}{n}$.

Now there are in total $(2n-1)$ trucks + cars leaving the given car. But out of those, $n$ are trucks. The probability that both to its left and right are trucks is,

$ \displaystyle \frac{n}{2n-1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{2n-2} = \frac{n}{2(2n-1)}$

Multiplying them gets you the desired probability.

Alternatively, choose $2$ trucks out of $n$ to be on the left and right of the given car. Then we can permute all the cars and trucks in $(2n-2)!$ ways.

So the desired probability is $~ \displaystyle 2 \cdot {n \choose 2} \cdot (2n-2)! ~/~ (2n)!$

Answer (score 0):

The expected count of stuck cars may be evaluated using the Linearity of Expectation.

Let $X_i$ indicate that a car $i$ is stuck, by equaling $1$ when it is stuck, and $0$ otherwise. Then: $$\mathsf E(X_i)=0\cdot\mathsf P(X_i=0)+1\cdot\mathsf P(X_i=1)$$

Now the count of stuck cars is the sum of these indicators: $$\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E({\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^n} X_i)$$

You've attempted to evaluate $\mathsf P(X_i=1)$ , but erroneously.  The probability for a particular car not being in an end lane is indeed $(2n-2)/(2n)$.

However, the the second condition is: the event *obtaining two from the trucks, when selecting two from the remaining vehicles*, to be positioned beside the particular car, given that it is not in an end lane.

Comment: Can you show the right calculations for P(Xi)?

Comment: @Dan As Graham Kemp's answer indicated, when computing $p(X_i),$ the first factor of  $~\displaystyle \frac{2n-2}{2n}~$ is correct, while the 2nd factor is wrong.  The 2nd factor might be calculated in one of two ways.  Either manually, via $$\frac{n}{2n-1} \times \frac{n-1}{2n-2}$$ or (equivalently) combinatorically, via $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$ where $~\displaystyle N = \binom{n}{2}, ~D = \binom{2n-1}{2}.$